# Google API: Using requestAccessToken() without a popup? (Ionic/Capacitor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am using the following code to get a client token from Google in order to access the user's calendar. This works absolutely fine on Desktop.

However, on my Capacitor mobile app, a popup can not be opened out of the box.

So my question is: Is there possibility to authenticate my client without a popup?

```
    const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: '{id}',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/calendar',
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            googleGetEvents(tokenResponse.access_token);
            return tokenResponse.access_token;
        }
    });

    client.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' }); // prompt '' is required to avoid the consent screen
```